# Compare JavaScript Array of Objects to Get Min / Max With 2 Properties At the Same Time

Tags: javascript

```
var items = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200, "Count": 4},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000, "Count": 2},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 5, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 6, "Cost": 50, "Count": 8}
]
```

I want to get the lowest Cost item, and if many of them are the same cost, I want to get the one with the highest count, and if there are still multiple, I want to get a random item.

```
var lowestCost = items.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.Cost < curr.Cost ? prev : curr;
});
```

This is the way to get the lowest cost, any simple way to do the other comparisons simultaneously?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by simultaneously?

Comment: @MichaelBianconi sorry it's not a real requirement, I just mean the simplest possible way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get an array of the reduced data set and then take a random object.

```js
var items = [{ ID: 1, Cost: 200, Count: 4 }, { ID: 2, Cost: 1000, Count: 2 }, { ID: 3, Cost: 50, Count: 10 }, { ID: 4, Cost: 50, Count: 10 }, { ID: 5, Cost: 50, Count: 10 }, { ID: 6, Cost: 50, Count: 8 }],
    result = items.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r || r[0].Cost > o.Cost || r[0].Cost === o.Cost && r[0].Count < o.Count) {
            return [o];
        }
        if (r[0].Cost === o.Cost && r[0].Count === o.Count) {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, null);


console.log(result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)]); // random
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This looks like the only way, need to keep an array of lowest cost items around so you can choose one. I guess there's no way to have a random answer in the initial output?

Comment: `return [ o, [...r, o], [r]][ Math.sign( (r.Cost - o[0].Cost) || (r.Count - o[0].Count) ) + 1 ]` ... Was just code-golfing ...

Comment: @harry no, cause you don't know how many results you'll have while traversing, therefore you can't calculate the probability. For sure you can choose randomly while reducing, but then the last utem will occur much more often then the last

Comment: @JonasWilms What about Florian's answer?

Comment: @harry yes that has the problem described.

Answer (score 0):

```
  prev.Cost === curr.Cost && prev.Count > curr.Count || prev.Cost < curr.Cost
     ? prev
     :  curr
```

Or maybe more clever:

```
  ((prev.Cost - curr.Cost) || (prev.Count - curr.Count)) < 0 
     ? curr
     : prev
```

Comment: I didn't dv for what it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

A not so-random solution :

```js
const items = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200, "Count": 4},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000, "Count": 2},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 5, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 6, "Cost": 50, "Count": 8}
];

const computeLowestCost = () => {
      return items.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      const isEqualPriceAndCount = (prev.Cost === curr.Cost)
                              && (prev.Count === curr.Count);
                              
      if (isEqualPriceAndCount) {
        // return a random item if price and count are the same
        return (!!Math.round(Math.random()))
        ? prev
        : curr;
      }
    
      return !!((prev.Cost < curr.Cost) || (prev.Count > curr.Count))
      ? prev 
      : curr;
    });
}
const lowestCost = computeLowestCost();

console.log(lowestCost);


// Randomness...is not that random because
// 1st item has 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 chance to remain
// 2nd item has 1/2 * 1/2 chance to remain
// 3rd item has 1/2 chance to remain
const results = {};

for  (let i = 0; i < 1000000;i++) {
  const res = computeLowestCost();
  results[res.ID]= !!results[res.ID]
  ? ++results[res.ID]
  : 1;
}

console.log(results)
```

A more random solution :

```js
const items = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200, "Count": 4},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000, "Count": 2},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 5, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 6, "Cost": 50, "Count": 8}
];
const shuffle = (array) => array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

const computeLowestCost = () => {
      shuffle(items);
      return items.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
      const isEqualPriceAndCount = (prev.Cost === curr.Cost)
                              && (prev.Count === curr.Count);
                              
      if (isEqualPriceAndCount) {
        // return a random item if price and count are the same
        return (!!Math.round(Math.random()))
        ? prev
        : curr;
      }
    
      return !!((prev.Cost < curr.Cost) || (prev.Count > curr.Count))
      ? prev 
      : curr;
    });
}
const lowestCost = computeLowestCost();

console.log(lowestCost);


// Randomness...almost equally distributed
const results = {};

for  (let i = 0; i < 1000000;i++) {
  const res = computeLowestCost();
  results[res.ID]= !!results[res.ID]
  ? ++results[res.ID]
  : 1;
}

console.log(results)

// For more randomness we could shuffle the array initially
```

Comment: @Harry I added random

Comment: Hmm I don't understand how this works `return (!!Math.round(Math.random()))`

Comment: @Harry : `Math.random()` will give you a number between 0 and 1. `Math.round()` will then floor the number to 0 or ceil it to 1. The `!!` converts the value to boolean. So if we have `Math.Random() >= 0.5` it will be true, else, it will be false. Because `Math.round(0.5) === 1` and 1 is truthy.

Comment: Can you explain why this works in general. Nina's answer is very simple to me but I don't understand why having a random there does the trick.

Comment: @Harry I made you a robust random solution by shuffling your array. The first solution is not-that random as you can see by running code snippet

Comment: Oh ok so the random thing, this is the problem that Jonas Wilms was talking about.

Comment: This is random, but the randomness is not equally distributed. The last item has 50% probability.

Comment: @JonasWilms ok got it. Thanks for all your help everyone.

Comment: @JonasWilms it is if you shuffle the array at beginning. (see second snippet)

Comment: But that shuffling is `O(log n * n)`, also it is still not equally distributed (but there is less bias)

Answer (score 0):

So a not so simple way would be to just do another ternary right afterwards to figure out if it was equal to or greater than. And then we would have another ternary to figure out which one has the higher count etc...

```
var items = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200, "Count": 4},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000, "Count": 2},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 5, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 6, "Cost": 50, "Count": 8}
]

var lowestCost = items.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    return prev.Cost < curr.Cost ? prev: (prev.Cost == curr.Cost ? (prev.Count > curr.Count ? prev: curr) : curr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array to contain costs and create an array to contain count. Pick out the min value from cost and max value from the count. Filter the array and compare them. The code is self-explanatory. Comments for further explanation

```js
var items = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200, "Count": 4},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000, "Count": 2},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 5, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 6, "Cost": 50, "Count": 8}
]
let costs = items.map(objs => Number(objs["Cost"])) // get all the costs from the items
let counts = items.map(objs => Number(objs["Count"])) //.. get all the counts from the items
let mincost = Math.min(...costs) // get the mininum cost
let maxcount = Math.max(...counts) // get the max cost
let answer = items.filter((objs) => { // filter the items array
 if (objs["Cost"] == mincost){ // if the cost is minimum
   if (objs["Count"] == maxcount) { // if the count is maximum
     return objs // return the object
    }
  }
})
if (answer.length >= 1) { // if more than one answers
  let random = answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * answer.length)]; // return a random value
  console.log(random);
}else{
  console.log(answer) // else just log the value
}
```

`Math.floor(Math.random() * answer.length)` this gives you a random number in the range of the length of the array. So you can just plug it into the array's selector.

This translates to

```js
var items = [{"ID": 1, "Cost": 200, "Count": 4},{"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000, "Count": 2},{"ID": 3, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},{"ID": 4, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},{"ID": 5, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},{"ID": 6, "Cost": 50, "Count": 8}]
let mincost = Math.min(...items.map(objs => Number(objs["Cost"])))
let maxcount = Math.max(...items.map(objs => Number(objs["Count"])))
let answer = items.filter(objs => objs["Cost"] == mincost && objs["Count"] == maxcount)
if (answer.length >= 1) {
let random = answer[Math.floor(Math.random() * answer.length)];
  console.log(random);
}else{
  console.log(answer)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

- Randomize array
- Loop through randomized array, use object to hold max and min value
- If the value is not available on `min` and `max` initialize with current value
- Check if the price is less than or equal to min value, if it is equal and count is same keep the previous one else update with new value
- In same way check for greater or equal than max value and update accordingly

```js
var items = [
    {"ID": 1, "Cost": 200, "Count": 4},
    {"ID": 2, "Cost": 1000, "Count": 2},
    {"ID": 3, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 4, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 5, "Cost": 50, "Count": 10},
    {"ID": 6, "Cost": 50, "Count": 8}
]

let randomizeArray = _.shuffle(items)

let op = randomizeArray.reduce((op,inp)=>{
  op.max = op.max || inp
  op.min = op.min || inp
  if(inp.Cost <= op.min.Cost){
    if((op.min.Cost > inp.Cost) || (op.min.Count < inp.Count)){
      op.min = inp
    } 
  }
  if(inp.Cost >= op.max.Cost){
    if((op.max.Cost < inp.Cost) || (op.max.Count < inp.Count)){
      op.max = inp
    }
  }
  return op
},{})

console.log(op)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not entirely sure but I feel like this would be slower than Nina's answer?

Comment: @Harry if you count both will have `O(n)` time complexity, in real scenarios i don't think there will be much significant difference, and if you compare with space complexity this will have `O(1)` whereas in worst case scenario if all the elements are identical that will have `O(n)`

Comment: More importantly that shuffling duplicates items.

Comment: @JonasWilms a valid point, i just overlooked that, let me see if i can assure that no duplicates

Comment: @JonasWilms added loadash `shuffle` method to avoid that condition

Answer (score 0):

```
items = items.sort((a,b) => a.Cost < b.Cost ? -1 : (a.Cost == b.Cost ? 0 : 1))
items = items.filter(item => item.Count == items[0].Count)
return items.length != 0 ? items[0] : null
```

This will do it